# C# : how to use parameters for SQL Server stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to use stored procedures in C# to get data from a SQL Server table. I want to print the city with the id that I'll pass as a parameter, but I don't know the correct syntax of using parameters like that for a stored procedure in C#.

This is the C# code that I'm using:

```
string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnString"].ConnectionString;

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SP_GetCityByID where id = 2", conn);
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    SqlParameter param = command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);
    param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    Console.WriteLine(param.Value);
}
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SP_GetCityByID ", conn);
```

You don't put a `where` condition when you call a stored procedure. `where` condition needs to be inside the body of stored procedure which should compare the `id` column of your city table with `@ID` parameter you are passing to stored procedure. Secondly, `ExecuteNonQuery` function which you have written at the end will not serve your purpose. Use `ExecuteScalar` function instead as given below:

```
String cityName= command.ExecuteScalar();
```

I am assuming your stored procedure accepts parameter `@ID` and returns matching city name in the form of table.

Comment: ok i do remember hearing about ExecuteScalar but i dont remeber what it is used for.  i kinda know not to put the parameter where i called the stored procedure but where DO i call the parameter? i need a place to write something like: "where id = 2"

Comment: The place to write the where condition is inside the stored procedure. And you should not write `where id= 2` because that would always return same result. Instead write `where id = @ID`.

Comment: `ExecuteScalar` is used get single value results from database. Inside your stored procedure write a query to get city name on the basis of @ID parameter

Comment: yeah i know that, i have that part in the stored procedure.  but can't i give the parameter to the stored procedure in the visual studio using c#?
in the code i have up there?

Comment: For sending value add line `param.Value= <your id value>` before the statement executing the command. Also you should use `AddWithValue` instead of `Add` function for specifying parameters

Comment: Thank you i remember some now of how to use that.  this is the new code with your help:  SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SP_GetCityByID", conn);
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID", 2);
                //command.ExecuteScalar();
                Console.WriteLine(command.ExecuteScalar());

Answer (score 0):

provide parameter as below:

```
  string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SP_GetCityByID", conn);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlParameter param = command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 2;
        //param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Console.WriteLine(param.Value);

    }
```

Comment: not working. visual studio throw me red error when i type the value like you suggested