# Abstract concrete SQL query with WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

This is my specific sql query (ms sql)

```
SELECT SUM(Sum2) AS Sum 
FROM   (SELECT ROUND(bidsum,2) AS Sum2 
        FROM   TableDocuments 
        WHERE  MANeu = 'AS400' 
        and    Art = '3' 
        and    DokumentTyp = '3' 
        and    offernumber = 'AB.1234.56'
       ) src
```

In my application I run this query to calculate the volume of orders (Sum), write it in the column `volumeoforders` and show it in the gui. But there I've a concrete offernumber.

Now I need a sql script, view or program which does this for all offernumbers not only for 'AB.1234.56'.

What is a good way to do this?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I think using parameters in query is a way to go for you. Assuming you are using .NET this is solution for stored procedure, but you use it in the same way with queries: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43953617/c-sharp-how-to-use-parameters-for-sql-server-stored-procedure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [GROUP BY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql) you can get this information for every `offernumber`, as below:

```
SELECT src.offernumber, SUM(src.Sum2) AS Sum 
FROM (
       SELECT offernumber, ROUND(bidsum,2) AS Sum2 
       FROM TableDocuments 
       WHERE MANeu = 'AS400' and Art = '3' and DokumentTyp = '3' 
     ) src
GROUP BY src.offernumber
```

Comment: simple and appropriate